# Trying to convert pandas DataFrame structure with list values to tensorflow DataSet

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm building an DNNRegressor using tensorflow and my problem comes from the process of converting my features which are stored as a pandas DataFrame into tensorflow Dataset structures. 
More specifically, from the use of both `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` and the feature columns function I created.

I was led to believe from this [tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns#numeric_column) that it would be possible to create a data structure with a multi-dimensional feature. In the guide it is mentioned that when creating a `feature_column`, it is possible to specify the shape of the feature. Two examples are given, a 10 element vector under the key `"Bowling"` and a 10x5 matrix under the key `"MyMatrix"`. Following the example, I created some multi-dimensional features. For simplicity, I created an example code which I post below with two multi-dimensional features using a pandas DataFrame, under `"matrix"` there are two examples of 2x2 matrices and under `"vector"` two examples of 3 element vectors. There are two outputs for each of the two examples, an x and y (I've seen nothing to support that this representation is possible, however this would be the most convenient in the context of the problem)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

# Create features DataFrame
feature_header = ['matrix', 'vector']
feature_table = [ [ [[1, 2], [3,4]], [5,6,7] ],
                 [ [[8, 9], [10,11]], [12,13,14] ] ]
features = pd.DataFrame(feature_table, columns=feature_header)

# Create outputs DataFrame
header_targets = ['x', 'y']
table_targets = [ [7, 8],
                 [9, 10] ]
labels = pd.DataFrame(table_targets, columns=header_targets)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
```

An error occurs in the last line when converting to a tensorflow Dataset

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

My question is, is it possible to do this conversion? I am able to do the conversion if I create a new column for each of the element of the matrix/vector but this becomes rather chaotic when the matrix is of size 12x12.

I'm using tensorflow version 1.13.1 and python 3.6.4

**EDIT**

Tried using numpy multidimensional arrays instead of lists, changed the feature table declaration to the following

```
feature_table = [ [ np.array([[1, 2], [3,4]]), np.array([5,6,7]) ],
                 [ np.array([[8, 9], [10,11]]), np.array([12,13,14]) ] ]
```

Got the following error

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: It's possible to use multidimensional array, but not lists

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I edited the post. I tried to use numpy arrays but the error keeps occurring

Comment: it's not array, but array of lists